# Setting valueless boolean attributes with the tag function

Tags: attribute, tag, function

When using the [tag function](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/functions.html#tag), how does one handle valueless attributes which could also be null?

For example, it's great we can do…

```
{% set idVar   = 'idstring' %}
{% set nameVar = 'namestring' %}
{% set typeVar = 'typestring' %}

{{ tag('input', {
    id: idVar,
    name: nameVar,
    type: typeVar
}) }}
```

…to generate:

```
<input id="idstring" name="namestring" type="typestring">
```

But what about if the `required` attribute is also a variable? We can’t do:

```
{% set reqVar  = '' %}

{% if field is required %}
    {% set reqVar = 'required' %}
{% endif %}

{{ tag('input', {
    id: idVar,
    name: nameVar,
    required: reqVar
}) }}
```

…because if `reqVar` is empty, one would want the `required` attribute to not be written at all. To generate:

```
<input id="idstring" name="namestring" type="typestring">
```

…and **not**:

```
<input id="idstring" name="namestring" type="typestring" required>
```

The same thing applies to other boolean attributes like `hidden`.

Is there a way to do this with this function? What am I missing or not getting?

Answer (score 4):

If an attribute is set to `true`, it will get added without a value.

```
{{ tag('input', {
    id: idVar,
    name: nameVar,
    required: true
}) }}
```

Also, if it is set to `null` or `false`, it will be omitted, as if it was never listed in the first place.

Comment: Great. So the function knows which attribute names are _allowed_ to be boolean. Presumably inherited from knowledge embedded in Yii?

Comment: Assuming I have understood correctly, it would be good if this could be noted in the docs.

Comment: The [docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/functions.html#tag) link to [yii\helpers\BaseHtml::renderTagAttributes()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#renderTagAttributes()-detail) which has a full description of the different types of attributes/values that are supported.